# Pass info from PreferenceActivity to ControlExtension SW2

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to pass data from the `PreferenceActivity` to the `ControlExtension` and I don't really know how to do that. 
I'm trying to use the `BroadcastReceiver` solution, because `SharedPreferences` doesn't work for my, but without knowing how yo use it so, ¿how and where I should register the `BroadcastReceiver` for the SW2?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I'm using now `BroadcastReceiver` but I ¿How do I have register my `BroadcastReceiver` in the `ControlExtension`? or ¿How do I start my `ControlExtension` from the `ExtensionReceiver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access shared preferences this way, e.g:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
int jpegQuality = Integer.parseInt( prefs.getString(mContext.getString(R.string.preference_key_jpeg_quality), "0") );
```

Set the mContext in your ControlExtension constructor, where you receive a Context.

Comment: So, I did: `SharedPreferences preferences = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("comandos", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);` and `public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) { preferences.edit().putString("amarillo", "amarillo").commit();
 return true;}` on the preference activity onCreate and `prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext); String comando = prefs.getString("amarillo","NULL");
        if (comando.equals("amarillo"))
          Log.d(TAG, "amarillo");` onResume Control Extension and doesn't work